# Python Produce empty list if condition not satisafied

Tags: python, list

I am creating a `if` condition-based list. I want to create an empty list if the condition is not satisfied.

**My code:**

```
ip_list = []
op_list= [ip_list[0] if len(ip_list)>0 else '']
```

**Present output:**

```
op_list = ['']
```

**Expected output:**

```
op_list = []
```

Comment: Are you looking for `[ip_list[0]] if len(ip_list)>0 else []`?

Comment: @Brian I think it would create `[[ ]]`. Right? Not `[ ]`.

Comment: Nope, it would create `[]`

Comment: @SethMMorton That's right. It does create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be accomplished more succinctly via slicing:

```
op_list = ip_list[:1]
```

If `ip_list` has at least one element, `op_list` will be a singleton list with the first element of `ip_list`. Otherwise, `op_list` will be an empty list.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = []
>>> a[:1]
[1]
>>> b[:1]
[]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
op_list = [] if ip_list else [ip_list[0]]
```

Comment: That's going to throw an index out of range if ip_list is empty. You either want `if not ip_list` or switch the `True` and `False` sides.

Answer (score 0):

You only need the first element if `ip_list` has any.
Here is one of the easiest solution for that:

```
[ip_list[0]] if ip_list else []
```